# How to set a path for backgroundImage in React JS correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When inserting an `img`, the path to the image works as intended:

```
import Background from "./img/bg.webp";
...
<div>
    <img className='bg' src={Background} />
</div>
```

When the same path is used for the `backgroundImage` property, the background is not displayed:

```
<div style={ { backgroundImage: "./img/bg.webp"}}></div>
```

Here is the `src` folder structure: 
[src folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC9wS.png)

How to set the backgroundImage path correctly?

Comment: In the second example you also need to import the image before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion of image background for div tag works differently.

For div

```
<div style={ { backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`}}></div>
```